# Is there any way to use a more modern language with Pick Basic? D3 to be exact

Tags: basic, multivalue, pick

So been on the Pick system since the 70s.  Everything we have is done in Pick.  I would like to maintain the Pick records but use another language such as Java for front end user interfaces.  The issue is D3 seems to be locked away in the linux server with no hope of actually grabbing the data.  Any pick user ever find a solution?

Comment: Rocket is D3's current vendor and they provide solutions for you to extend D3 into other things. They also own and operate other flavors of Pick like UniVerse and UniData that have additional options, so some customers choose to migrate from D3 to those flavors. Further still there are Pick flavors from other vendors like MVON# from ONgroup and OpenQM and jBASE from Zumasys that all have options for breaking down those walls around your Pick data. Disclaimer--I'm a Zumasys employee and jBASE proponent though I was a D3 customer in my last life!

Comment: Should add, leaving that commentary as context for the general question at hand here but not necessarily to present as an answer. It skews much more towards a sales conversation than a technical answer. I'd be looking to someone from Rocket to provide a D3 specific answer here for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. we can use modern UI technologies on the above of pick system and it can be communicated with d3 systems using api.